# Why gets is not storing the values in the variable?

Tags: c++

I was practicing c++, and i made a simple program which asks some details and then stores it in a structure. The code looks like the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct signup_form{
    char name[];
    char email[];
    unsigned int age;
    char usr_name[];
    char pass[];
};

void signup(){
    signup_form prsn;
    cout<<"\n\tName: ";
    gets(prsn.name);
    cout<<"\n\n\tE-mail: ";
    gets(prsn.email);
    cout<<"\n\n\tage";
    cin>>prsn.age;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"\n\n\tUsername: ";
    gets(prsn.usr_name);
    cout<<"\n\n\tPassword: ";
    gets(prsn.pass);

    cout<< prsn.usr_name<<"\t"<<prsn.pass<<"\t"<<prsn.name<<"\t"<<prsn.email;
    return;
}

int main(){
    signup();
    return 0;
}
```

the problem is in the output, its output looks like the following:
[image: error]

the last printed line is the output of the line  `cout<< prsn.usr_name<<"\t"<<prsn.pass<<"\t"<<prsn.name<<"\t"<<prsn.email;`. You can see this clearly that username and the password are the same all though their value were entered different and the name, age and the email were not entered then...

why it is giving me this error?

Comment: You don't have any memory allocated for your `char` arrays.

Comment: If you practice C++, you should learn about `std::string `. Stop writing C.

Comment: If this code doesn't spew at least a stack of warnings at compile time, I'm amazed. And a C++14 compliant compiler won't eat it *at all* (no `gets`, hallelujah!)

Comment: yes it gave me a warning

Comment: Did that really compile? I don't write in C++, but those array members in the struct can't be right.

Comment: yes, that's why i showed you the output

Comment: The code *looks like* the following? Post your *actual* code, please.

Comment: @a3f Unfortunately it [compiles with GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ImPQZP1p4Es6uEBj).

Comment: well actually i was practicing those things which i was taught in my school

Comment: @MikeCAT Oh, it's interpreted as a zero size array. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your struct to look like this (if you insisting on using char[] instead of std::string of course):

```
struct signup_form{
    char name[100];
    char email[100];
    unsigned int age;
    char usr_name[100];
    char pass[100];
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using character strings without allocating any memory to it.

There are 2 simple (assuming simple input) ways to fix this:

```
const int MAX_STR_SIZE = 256;
struct signup_form{
  char name[MAX_STR_SIZE];
  char email[MAX_STR_SIZE];
  unsigned int age;
  char usr_name[MAX_STR_SIZE];
  char pass[MAX_STR_SIZE];
};
```

or more efficient way (from memory management point of view) you could use class string from standard C++ library:

```
struct signup_form{
  std::string name;
  std::string email;
  unsigned int age;
  std::string usr_name;
  std::string pass;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

As others already pointed in the comments, you are doing something wrong. And I am not talking about error in your code. You are mixing C and C++. Some people think, that C++ is superset or C, but this is not true. If you are willing to learn C++, use C++ and not C. They are different languages.

Now, according to your code. You have `char[]` which is low-level version of C++'s standard [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and requires memory management by user.

`gets` is C-like function, which requires allocated memory in destination. You did not provide any space for it.

To fix your code, use C++

```
struct signup_form{
    std::string name;
    std::string email;
    unsigned int age;
    std::string usr_name;
    std::string pass;
};

void signup(){
    signup_form prsn;
    cout << "\n\tName: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, prsn.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the `char var[]` in the struct with `string var;`

Substitute the

```
gets(prns.var)
```

with

```
cin >> prns.var;
```

Give it try.